# How can MS Access work with an encrypted field in a Linked SQL Server table?

Tags: encryption, databases, sql-server

I have an MS Access .accdb file that acts as a front-end to a SQL Server database.  There is a table that holds SSNs in plain text.  We want to encrypt those SSNs in the table so that, the user can input them in plain text, they get encrypted when stored, then when they're read by certain forms/reports, they're decrypted.  What's the best way to go about achieving this?

If there is a solution in VBA, then what about forms where VBA isn't used to update/insert data?  MS Access forms are designed to update/insert data on the fly rather than rely on Insert/Update statements in VBA.  So, if a VBA option is the *only* option, then I have to basically scrap ALL forms and start over (or implement some kind of hidden field on each form that gets updated whenever the "plain text" SSN field is updated.

***Note:*** I have a feeling that the answer to this question is, "You idiot!  You're using Access!" But, for S&G, let's pretend I work in a place where I have no control over what platform is being used and I have to make due with what I've been given to work with.

Comment: You could encrypt in a trigger on the SQL server. I'm not convinced this gives any benefit over column permissions. +1 for specifying your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You idiot!  You're using Access!  Stop that!

However, if you absolutely have to, a quick Google search shows VBA can call the Windows API, so, per [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84d49593-2d8e-4e7c-af3a-61882af9557d/access-to-cryptencrypt-cryptoapiwinapi-functions-in-vba?forum=isvvba), here's some starting sample code (unverified):

```
'Paste this code in a Class Module, named clsCryptoFilterBox

Option Explicit

Private Declare Function CryptAcquireContext Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptAcquireContextA" (phProv As Long, pszContainer As String, pszProvider As String, ByVal dwProvType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptCreateHash Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, phHash As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptDeriveKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal hBaseData As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, phKey As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptDestroyHash Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hHash As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptDestroyKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptEncrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal Final As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pbData As String, pdwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwBufLen As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptDecrypt Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal Final As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pbData As String, pdwDataLen As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptExportKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hKey As Long, ByVal hExpKey As Long, ByVal dwBlobType As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pbData As String, pdwDataLen As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptGenKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal Algid As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, phKey As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptGetProvParam Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwParam As Long, pbData As Any, pdwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptGetUserKey Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwKeySpec As Long, phUserKey As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptHashData Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal pbData As String, ByVal dwDataLen As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptReleaseContext Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal hProv As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptSignHash Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptSignHashA" (ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal dwKeySpec As Long, ByVal sDescription As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal pbSignature As String, pdwSigLen As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CryptVerifySignature Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "CryptVerifySignatureA" (ByVal hHash As Long, ByVal pbSignature As String, ByVal dwSigLen As Long, ByVal hPubKey As Long, ByVal sDescription As String, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

'API error function

Private Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'API memory functions

Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GlobalFree Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub CpyMemValAdrFromRefAdr Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal hpvDest As Any, hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)

Private Declare Sub CpyMemRefAdrFromValAdr Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (hpvDest As Any, ByVal hpvSource As Any, ByVal cbCopy As Long)

'constants for API memory functions

Private Const GMEM_MOVEABLE = &H2

Private Const GMEM_ZEROINIT = &H40

Private Const GHND = (GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT)

'constants for Cryptography API functions

Private Const MS_DEF_PROV = "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0"

Private Const PROV_RSA_FULL = 1

Private Const CRYPT_NEWKEYSET = &H8

Private Const PP_CONTAINER = 6

Private Const AT_KEYEXCHANGE = 1

Private Const AT_SIGNATURE = 2

Private Const SIMPLEBLOB = 1

Private Const ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT = 24576

Private Const ALG_CLASS_HASH = 32768

Private Const ALG_TYPE_ANY = 0

Private Const ALG_TYPE_BLOCK = 1536

Private Const ALG_TYPE_STREAM = 2048

Private Const ALG_SID_RC2 = 2

Private Const ALG_SID_RC4 = 1

Private Const ALG_SID_MD5 = 3

Private Const CALG_MD5 = ((ALG_CLASS_HASH Or ALG_TYPE_ANY) Or ALG_SID_MD5)

Private Const CALG_RC2 = ((ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT Or ALG_TYPE_BLOCK) Or ALG_SID_RC2)

Private Const CALG_RC4 = ((ALG_CLASS_DATA_ENCRYPT Or ALG_TYPE_STREAM) Or ALG_SID_RC4)

'constants from WinErr.h

Private Const NTE_NO_KEY As Long = -2146893811 '0x8009000DL

Private Const NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE As Long = -2146893818

'clsCryptoFilterBox constants

Private Const CFB_BUSY = 0

Private Const CFB_READY = 1

Private Const CFB_VALID = 2

Private Const ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM = CALG_RC4

Private Const ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE = 1

Private Const CRYPT_EXPORTABLE = 1

'private property buffers

Private sInBuffer As String

Private sOutBuffer As String

Private sPassword As String

Private sSignature As String

Private lStatus As Long

Public Property Get InBuffer() As String

InBuffer = sInBuffer

End Property

Public Property Let InBuffer(vNewValue As String)

sInBuffer = vNewValue

End Property

Public Property Get OutBuffer() As String

OutBuffer = sOutBuffer

End Property

Public Property Get Signature() As String

Signature = sSignature

End Property

Public Property Let Signature(vNewValue As String)

sSignature = vNewValue

End Property

Public Sub Sign()

'Create a signature for Inbuffer and place in Signature

Dim sContainer As String, sDescription As String, sProvider As String, lHCryptprov As Long

Dim lHHash As Long, lResult As Long, lSignatureLen As Long

On Error GoTo ErrSign

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_BUSY

'init Signature property

sSignature = ""

'Get handle to the default provider.

sContainer = vbNullChar

sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV & vbNullChar

If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(lHCryptprov, ByVal sContainer, ByVal sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptAcquireContext!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

'Create a hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptCreateHash(lHCryptprov, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, lHHash)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptCreateHash!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

If Not CBool(CryptHashData(lHHash, sInBuffer, Len(sInBuffer), 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptHashData!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

'Sign hash object.

'Determine size of signature.

sDescription = vbNullChar

lResult = CryptSignHash(lHHash, AT_SIGNATURE, sDescription, 0, sSignature, lSignatureLen)

sSignature = String(lSignatureLen, vbNullChar)

'Sign hash object (with signature key).

If Not CBool(CryptSignHash(lHHash, AT_SIGNATURE, sDescription, 0, sSignature, lSignatureLen)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError()) & " during CryptSignHash")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

ReleaseHandles:

'Destroy hash object.

If lHHash Then lResult = CryptDestroyHash(lHHash)

'Release provider handle.

If lHCryptprov Then lResult = CryptReleaseContext(lHCryptprov, 0)

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_READY

Exit Sub

ErrSign:

MsgBox ("ErrSign " & Error$)

GoTo ReleaseHandles

End Sub

Public Sub Validate()

'Validate InBuffer with Signature and assign Status with result

Dim bValid As Boolean, sContainer As String, sDescription As String, sProvider As String

Dim lDataLen As Long, lDataPoint As Long, lHCryptprov As Long, lHHash As Long

Dim lResult As Long, lSignatureLen As Long, lHCryptKey As Long

ReDim aByteData(0) As Byte

On Error GoTo ErrValidate

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_BUSY

'init internal valid flag

bValid = True

'Get handle to the default provider.

sContainer = vbNullChar

sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV & vbNullChar

If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(lHCryptprov, ByVal sContainer, ByVal sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) Then

bValid = False

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptAcquireContext!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

'Create a hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptCreateHash(lHCryptprov, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, lHHash)) Then

bValid = False

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptCreateHash!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

'Add data to hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptHashData(lHHash, sInBuffer, Len(sInBuffer), 0)) Then

bValid = False

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptHashData!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

'Determine size of signature.

'sDescription = vbNullChar

'lResult = CryptSignHash(lHHash, AT_SIGNATURE, sDescription, 0, 0, lSignatureLen)

'Get handle to signature key.

If Not CBool(CryptGetUserKey(lHCryptprov, AT_SIGNATURE, lHCryptKey)) Then

bValid = False

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptGetUserKey!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

lSignatureLen = Len(sSignature)

'Verify signature.

If Not CBool(CryptVerifySignature(lHHash, sSignature, lSignatureLen, lHCryptKey, sDescription, 0)) Then

If GetLastError = NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE Then

bValid = False

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

Else

bValid = False

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptVerifySignature!")

GoTo ReleaseHandles:

End If

End If

ReleaseHandles:

'Release signature key.

If lHCryptKey Then lResult = CryptDestroyKey(lHCryptKey)

'Destroy hash object.

If lHHash Then lResult = CryptDestroyHash(lHHash)

'Release provider handle.

If lHCryptprov Then lResult = CryptReleaseContext(lHCryptprov, 0)

Select Case bValid

Case True

lStatus = CFB_VALID

Case Else

lStatus = CFB_READY

End Select

Exit Sub

ErrValidate:

MsgBox ("ErrValidate " & Error$)

Resume

End Sub

Public Sub Encrypt()

'Encrypt InBuffer into OutBuffer

Dim lHExchgKey As Long, lHCryptprov As Long, lHHash As Long, lHkey As Long

Dim lResult As Long, sContainer As String, sProvider As String, sCryptBuffer As String

Dim lCryptLength As Long, lCryptBufLen As Long

On Error GoTo ErrEncrypt

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_BUSY

'Get handle to the default provider

sContainer = vbNullChar

sProvider = vbNullChar

sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV & vbNullChar

If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(lHCryptprov, ByVal sContainer, ByVal sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptAcquireContext!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Create a hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptCreateHash(lHCryptprov, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, lHHash)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptCreateHash!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Hash in the password data.

If Not CBool(CryptHashData(lHHash, sPassword, Len(sPassword), 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptHashData!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Derive a session key from the hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptDeriveKey(lHCryptprov, ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, lHHash, 0, lHkey)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptDeriveKey!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Destroy the hash object.

CryptDestroyHash (lHHash)

lHHash = 0

'Prepare a string buffer for the CryptEncrypt function

lCryptLength = Len(sInBuffer)

lCryptBufLen = lCryptLength * 2

sCryptBuffer = String(lCryptBufLen, vbNullChar)

LSet sCryptBuffer = sInBuffer

'Encrypt data

If Not CBool(CryptEncrypt(lHkey, 0, 1, 0, sCryptBuffer, lCryptLength, lCryptBufLen)) Then

MsgBox ("bytes required:" & CStr(lCryptLength))

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptEncrypt!")

'GoTo Done

End If

sOutBuffer = Mid$(sCryptBuffer, 1, lCryptLength)

Done:

'Destroy session key.

If (lHkey) Then lResult = CryptDestroyKey(lHkey)

'Release key exchange key handle.

If lHExchgKey Then CryptDestroyKey (lHExchgKey)

'Destroy hash object.

If lHHash Then CryptDestroyHash (lHHash)

'Release provider handle.

If lHCryptprov Then lResult = CryptReleaseContext(lHCryptprov, 0)

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_READY

Exit Sub

ErrEncrypt:

MsgBox ("ErrEncrypt " & Error$)

Resume

End Sub

Public Sub Decrypt()

'Decrypt InBuffer into OutBuffer

Dim lHExchgKey As Long, lHCryptprov As Long, lHHash As Long, lHkey As Long

Dim lResult As Long, sContainer As String, sProvider As String

Dim sCryptBuffer As String, lCryptBufLen As Long, lCryptPoint As Long

Dim lPasswordPoint As Long, lPasswordCount As Long

On Error GoTo ErrDecrypt

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_BUSY

'Init sOutBuffer

sOutBuffer = ""

'Get handle to the default provider.

sContainer = vbNullChar

sProvider = vbNullChar

sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV & vbNullChar

If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(lHCryptprov, ByVal sContainer, ByVal sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptAcquireContext!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Create a hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptCreateHash(lHCryptprov, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, lHHash)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptCreateHash!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Hash in the password data.

If Not CBool(CryptHashData(lHHash, sPassword, Len(sPassword), 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptHashData!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Derive a session key from the hash object.

If Not CBool(CryptDeriveKey(lHCryptprov, ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, lHHash, 0, lHkey)) Then

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptDeriveKey!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Destroy the hash object.

CryptDestroyHash (lHHash)

lHHash = 0

'Prepare sCryptBuffer for CryptDecrypt

lCryptBufLen = Len(sInBuffer) * 2

sCryptBuffer = String(lCryptBufLen, vbNullChar)

LSet sCryptBuffer = sInBuffer

'Decrypt data

If Not CBool(CryptDecrypt(lHkey, 0, 1, 0, sCryptBuffer, lCryptBufLen)) Then

MsgBox ("bytes required:" & CStr(lCryptBufLen))

MsgBox ("Error " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptDecrypt!")

GoTo Done

End If

'Apply decrypted string from sCryptBuffer to private buffer for OutBuffer property

sOutBuffer = Mid$(sCryptBuffer, 1, Len(sInBuffer))

Done:

'Destroy session key.

If (lHkey) Then lResult = CryptDestroyKey(lHkey)

'Release key exchange key handle.

If lHExchgKey Then CryptDestroyKey (lHExchgKey)

'Destroy hash object.

If lHHash Then CryptDestroyHash (lHHash)

'Release provider handle.

If lHCryptprov Then lResult = CryptReleaseContext(lHCryptprov, 0)

'switch Status property

lStatus = CFB_READY

Exit Sub

ErrDecrypt:

MsgBox ("ErrDecrypt " & Error$)

GoTo Done

End Sub

Public Property Get Status() As Long

Status = lStatus

End Property

Private Function InitUser() As Long

Dim lHCryptprov As Long, lHCryptKey As Long, avProviderData(1000) As Byte

Dim lProviderDataAddress As Long, lProviderDataLen As Long, lDataSize As Long

Dim lResult As Long, sContainer As String, sProvider As String

Dim sUserName As String, lPoint As Long, lMemHandle As Long

Dim lReturn As Long, sBuffer As String

On Error GoTo ErrInitUser

'prepare string buffers

sContainer = vbNullChar

sProvider = MS_DEF_PROV & vbNullChar

'Attempt to acquire a handle to the default key container.

If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(lHCryptprov, ByVal sContainer, ByVal sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)) Then

'Create default key container.

If Not CBool(CryptAcquireContext(lHCryptprov, ByVal sContainer, ByVal sProvider, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_NEWKEYSET)) Then

MsgBox ("Error creating key container! " & CStr(GetLastError))

Exit Function

End If

'Get name of default key container.

lProviderDataLen = Len(avProviderData(0)) * (UBound(avProviderData) + 1)

If Not CBool(CryptGetProvParam(lHCryptprov, PP_CONTAINER, avProviderData(0), lProviderDataLen, 0)) Then

MsgBox ("Error getting user name! " & CStr(GetLastError))

avProviderData(0) = 0

End If

'Get sUserName from avProviderData()

lPoint = LBound(avProviderData)

While lPoint <= UBound(avProviderData)

If avProviderData(lPoint) <> 0 Then

sUserName = sUserName & Chr$(avProviderData(lPoint))

Else

lPoint = UBound(avProviderData)

End If

lPoint = lPoint + 1

Wend

MsgBox ("Create key container " & sUserName)

End If

'Attempt to get handle to signature key

If Not CBool(CryptGetUserKey(lHCryptprov, AT_SIGNATURE, lHCryptKey)) Then

If GetLastError = NTE_NO_KEY Then

MsgBox ("Create key exchange key pair")

If Not CBool(CryptGenKey(lHCryptprov, AT_SIGNATURE, 0, lHCryptKey)) Then

MsgBox ("Error during CryptGenKey! " & CStr(GetLastError))

Exit Function

Else

lResult = CryptDestroyKey(lHCryptprov)

End If

Else

MsgBox ("Error during CryptGetUserKey! " & CStr(GetLastError))

Exit Function

End If

End If

'Attempt to get handle to exchange key

If Not CBool(CryptGetUserKey(lHCryptprov, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, lHCryptKey)) Then

If GetLastError = NTE_NO_KEY Then

MsgBox ("Create key exchange key pair")

If Not CBool(CryptGenKey(lHCryptprov, AT_KEYEXCHANGE, 0, lHCryptKey)) Then

MsgBox ("Error during CryptGenKey! " & CStr(GetLastError))

Exit Function

Else

lResult = CryptDestroyKey(lHCryptprov)

End If

Else

MsgBox ("Error during CryptGetUserKey! " & CStr(GetLastError))

Exit Function

End If

End If

'release handle to provider

lResult = CryptReleaseContext(lHCryptprov, 0)

InitUser = True

Exit Function

ErrInitUser:

MsgBox ("ErrInitUser " & Error$)

Resume

End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

If InitUser = True Then

MsgBox ("InitUser OK")

Else

MsgBox ("InitUser failed")

End If

End Sub

Public Property Get Password() As String

Password = sPassword

End Property

Public Property Let Password(vNewValue As String)

sPassword = vNewValue

End Property
```